# Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, multipartform-data

I am trying upload images through `POST` Request in Swift.

Here my code :

```
func uploadImagesToRamdomURL(server_url:String){
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image, 0.9)

    let url = NSURL(string:server_url)
    println(url)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"

    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")

    println(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)

    var body = NSMutableData()

    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"htdocs\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(imageData)
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData(imageData)
    //body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


    var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

    var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    println("returnString \(returnString)")

}
```

I have searched & added all things required to upload.

But what making it giving me error "Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line you get this error?

Comment: in "returnString" i got this error..

Comment: i.e. from server. check your upload image is .jpeg or not

Comment: ok i will let check it.. let me know how can i make it independent of "jpeg" or "png" or any.

Comment: its JPEG image only.. and i have also tried with PNG ..but same error.

Comment: you append imageData twice   body.appendData(imageData)

Comment: this i have removed but still the same.. i want to upload images through "files[]" .. is it the same?